# Mysql Script not running in the server

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Hi Have below query which runs fine in the local but its not runing on server

getting below errors throwing:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO @sql
> FROM  mis_report_esign_done_productwise' at line 9

Do i need to enable anything in the server ? Please suggest

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when created_date = ''',
      created_date,
      ''' then NO_OF_ESIGN_SUCCESS else 0 end) AS ',
      created_date, ''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  mis_report_esign_done_productwise
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I tested this query with MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 but I get no syntax error. I get an error that the table does not exist, which is expected in my case. But that indicates it successfully parsed the syntax.

Comment: Your INTO is considered a column alias. Move INTO clause to the end of the query.

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();` on both local and server and include the result in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have made excessive use of ' single inverted commas in the query which could have made it ambiguous. Also you have used a case statement do you want to use it inside this query or trying to output it. Please try to use " alongside ' to make it understandable.